# Iniciar classe Fragment de outra Classe Fragment

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma classe `GuiaDaCidade`.

```
public class GuiaDaCidade extends Fragment {

    View rootView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.guia_da_cidade, null);

        View botaoPasseios = (View) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btpasseios);
        View botaoAgenda = (View) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btagenda);

        botaoPasseios.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),Passeios.class));    ///O que fazer aqui?
            }
        });

        botaoAgenda.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.agendanatal.com.br");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
```

E a Classe `Passeios`:

```
public class Passeios extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    private ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    private ExpandableListView expListView;
    private List<String> listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    private WebView webView;
    private View rootView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.guia_passeios, null);

        expListView = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listaexp);

        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        expandeAll();
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                mudaTela(groupPosition, childPosition);

                return false;
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
```

Como faco para iniciar a classe `Passeios` a partir da classe `GuiaDaCidade`? 
No metodo `onclickListener` da classe `GuiaDaCidade` ja tem +/- a ideia teórica do que quero, porem não funciona.

Comment: Maroni, com passar GuiaDaCidade para Passeios voce quer trocar um pelo outro..ou quer abrir uma nova Activity que contem a nova fragment Passeios? Voce pode esclarecer melhor?

Comment: abrir uma nova activity que contem Passeios.

Comment: Passeios tem esse layout   rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.guia_passeios, null);  Gostaria de mostrar ele, apenas isso .-.

Answer (score 1):

@Maroni o problema existe porque você chamou o método **StartActivity** e ao invés de uma Activity você passou o seu Fragment Passeio.
Um fragment só pode existir dentro de uma Activity e este só pode ser adicionado a uma Activity de forma dinâmica(**focarei minha resposta nesta forma**) ou estática.

- **Forma Dinamica**: Para adicionar o fragment dinamicamente, ou melhor enquanto a aplicação esta em execução, você precisa ter no layout da sua activity um FrameLayout com um id que será um contentor para você colocar o fragment.

exemplo : activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--Voce pode ter a toolbar aqui-->
<!--O framelayout para conter o fragment-->
     <FrameLayout 
           android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Com o layout da seguinte forma você pode adicionar remover ou substituir os fragments desse framelayout utilizando a class [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html) que contem métodos necessários para tal.

Sendo assim você teria uma Activity de nome ActivityGuia por exemplo e no onCreate você faria setContentView a um XML que nem o que dei no exemplo com um FrameLayout e adiciona o fragment GuiaPasseio a activity com uma linha similar a esta :

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container,new GuiaDaCidade()).commit();

Para atingir o objectivo que você colocou aqui na questão  deve criar uma outra Activity de nome ActivityPasseio(por exemplo) e seguir o mesmo processo de como adicionar o fragment Passeio a esta activity.

Assim que voce tiver cada fragment na sua activity, agora sim você pode utilizar o método startActivity passando um intent em que o 2 parâmetro é a classe da Activity passeio. A sua nova chamada ficaria mais ou menos assim:

Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity,ActivityPasseio.class);

startActivity(intent);